# 404 Assets Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm developing with play framework (2.2.1) and I'm having a problem. Every asset that is static in my project is not being published to public. coffescripts, less and js files work well, but images and css files does not go there...
I've put this in my routes file

```
GET         /assets/*file                     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET         /webjars/*file                    controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

Then I have the following structure inside app folder

```
assets
|-----images
|----------logo.png
|-----javascript
|----------main.js
|-----stylesheets
|----------main.css
```

And I'm calling in my html files like this:

```
@routes.Assets.at("images/logo.png")
```

When I see the compiled files, theres no image or stylesheets directories. If I change the name of the main.css to main.less, it works fine.
Anybody knows what is causing this?

**UPDATE**
Based on Templar I've changed the directory structure to this but nothing happened:

```
assets
|-----javascript
|----------main.js
|-----stylesheets
|----------main.less
public
|-----images
|----------logo.png
|-----javascript
|----------other.js
|-----stylesheets
|----------other.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified at `GET         /assets/*file                     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)` that 
static files like images or not complied css or js files have to be in the public directory inside your application. From your directory tree I assume there is not such a folder.

Comment: Well... I've created the public directory and moved the images and stylesheets to there and nothing happened

Comment: What is the content of your project/Build.scala?

Comment: I don't have this file. My build.sbt is in the root project. and I have just libraryDependencies and a playJavaSettings call in it

Comment: So what is the final conclusion? What was the issue exactly @Augusto?